# MySQL MD5 with column variable and salt

Tags: mysql

What is the syntax for MySQL MD5 with multiple variables and or salt?

Table column works as below

```
UPDATE table SET hash = md5(column)
```

Salt works as below

```
UPDATE table SET hash = md5('salt')
```

How do I combine these? As the following doesn't work

```
UPDATE table SET hash = md5(column,'salt')
```

I could not see an example in the MySQL reference manual. I have tried spaces, dots and + sign.

EDIT: This has nothing to do with passwords so please keep comments related to the post and not education on BCrypt.

Comment: I was going to write a disclaimer that this was not password related. May be a should have done to avoid slightly off topic comment :) I will add it to the post.

Comment: Obligatory [MD5 is easily broken](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure) disclaimer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function for values concatenation. For example:

```
UPDATE table SET hash = md5(CONCAT(column,'salt'));
```